# size_t, ptrdiff_t and std::vector::size()

Tags: c++

I thought that the correct type to use to store the difference between pointers was `ptrdiff_t`.

As such, I'm confused by the way that my `STL` (msvc 2010) implements it's `std::vector::size()` function. The return type is `size_t` (this is mandated by the standard, as far as I understand it) and yet it's computed as the difference of pointers:

```
// _Mylast, _Myfirst are of type pointer
// size_type, pointer are inherited from allocator<_Ty>
size_type size() const 
{
    return (this->_Mylast - this->_Myfirst);
}
```

Obviously, there's a bit of meta-magic that goes on in order to determine exactly what types `size_type` and `pointer` are. In order to be "sure" what types they are I checked this:

```
bool bs = std::is_same<size_t, std::vector<int>::size_type>::value;
bool bp = std::is_same<int * , std::vector<int>::pointer>::value;
// both bs and bp evaluate as true, therefore:
//   size_type is just size_t
//   pointer is just int*
```

Compiling the following with `/Wall` gives me a `signed-to-unsigned mismatch` for `mysize2`, but no warnings for `mysize1`:

```
std::vector<int> myvector(100);
int *tail = &myvector[99];
int *head = &myvector[ 0];
size_t mysize1 = myvector.size();
size_t mysize2 = (tail - head + 1);
```

Changing the type of `mysize2` to `ptrdiff_t` results in no warning.
Changing the type of `mysize1` to `ptrdiff_t` results in an `unsigned-to-signed mismatch`.

Obviously I'm missing something...

EDIT: I'm not asking how to suppress the warning, with a cast or a `#pragma disable(xxx)`. The issue I'm concerned about is that `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` may have different allowable ranges (they do on my machine).

Consider `std::vector<char>::max_size()`. My implementation returns a `max_size` equal to `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`. Since `vector::size()` is creating an intermediate value of type `ptrdiff_t` before casting to `size_t` it seems that there could be problems here - `ptrdiff_t` is not big enough to hold `vector<char>::max_size()`.

Comment: (size_t) (tail - head + 1); fix the warning? Is it not?

Comment: @iammilind, GS: Thanks, but not looking for a cast - see my edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, ptrdiff_t is a signed integral type of the same size as size_t.  It must be signed so that it can represent both `p1 - p2` and `p2 - p1`.

In the specific case of the internals of std::vector, the implementor is effectively deriving `size()` from `end() - begin()`.  Because of the guarantees of std::vector (contiguous, array based storage), the value of the end pointer will always be greater than the value of the begin pointer, and thus there is no risk of generating a negative value.  In fact, size_t will always be able to represent a larger positive range than will ptrdiff_t, as it doesn't have to use half its range to represent negative values.  Effectively, this means that the cast in this case from ptrdiff_t to size_t is a widening cast, which has well defined (and intuitively obvious) results.

Also, note that this is not the only possible implementation of std::vector.  It could just as easily be implemented as a single pointer and a size_t value holding the size, deriving `end()` as `begin() + size()`.  That implementation would also resolve your `max_size()` concern.  In reality, max_size is never actually attainable--it would require your program's entire address space to be allocated for the vector's buffer, leaving no room for the begin()/end() pointers, function call stack, etc.

Comment: Basically agree, but, in the `vector<char>` case I think `ptrdiff_t` overflows once the vector is `>= 2GB`, which is not the whole address space (on my 32bit machine), so you could actually have a problem here in practice, right?? Fully agree the "other" vector implementation you discuss would be robust in this case.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem in practice because the semantics of signed/unsigned casts are well defined and value-preserving in this case.  You're not going to get a runtime exception in C++ for any of those operations, so that just leaves the compile-time warning that MS has #pragma'd out in this case.

Comment: @Drew: It is true that a negative number casts to `unsigned` in a well-defined way, but if the subtraction itself _overflows_ a signed integer, I do not think the result is guaranteed by the spec.  However, any particular implementation of the library is free to depend on implementation details of the compiler, since they are bundled.  So if this compiler ensures math mod 2, the implementation is fine; that is the point.

Comment: @Drew, Nemo: So if you take the difference of two pointers the intermediate result is always `ptrdiff_t`. If the allocation was large enough, the subtraction may overflow, and (assuming 2's complement integer behaviour) you'll end up with a `-ve` intermediate. At this point casting to `size_t` is "value preserving" and you'll end up with the correct `+ve` `size_t` result in the end. But this is entirely dependent on 2's complement `ptrdiff_t` overflow behaviour. Have I got it straight??

Comment: The `std::vector` code is part of the implementation, and may depend on other parts of the implementation. Therefore, the MSVC vector can use conversions that are specific to MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with how std::vector::size() is implemented in STL.
The **this->_Mylast - this->_Myfirst == vector size** is mere an coincidental fact which relies on how the vector is implemented.

Plus MSVC STL vector implementation has an **#pragma warning(disable: 4244)** which removes the warning.

Comment: I hardly think that turning the warning off resolves the underlying issues. `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` may have different allowable ranges (they do on my 32bit machine at least), where `max(ptrdiff_t)` is half of `max(size_t)`

Comment: @Darren Since the code is written by the implementors they are well within reason to rely on the implicit conversion.

Comment: @Luc: As per my edit, it seems that `ptrdiff_t` is not large enough to hold `vector<char>::max_size`. How is it ok to rely on a silent cast?? Isn't there an overflow issue here??

Comment: @Darren Because they are the implementors. They can know better than the C++ specs -- they're implementing it.